# set Mod_rewrite for php download link

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i set this mod_rewrite for my url : but this not work .

URL :

```
index.php?module=Files&action=show&id=default&download=yes&id=$_REQUEST[id]
```

Mod_rewrite :

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.html
RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]+)?-([^/\.]+)?-([^/\.]+)?/([^/\.]+)/?$  index.php?module=Files&action=show&id=default&download=yes&id=$1 [L,NS]
```

What's My Problems?!

i see 404 error page.

Comment: Give us some additional data, what does it mean doesn't work? What URLs have you tried? Do you have RewriteEngine and rewriteBase set correctly?

Comment: Is there an error 500 on your server? Do other rewrite rules work? We need additional information in order to help you...

Comment: Sorry but for such question a "-1" is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/  index.php?module=Files&action=show&id=default&download=yes&id=$1
```

When you go to `Domain.com/download/something/` it will be `index.php?module=Files&action=show&id=default&download=yes&id=something`

Comment: lol! my url generate any file for download . your idea show download page .